# Why is it usually not ambiguous to nominalize a verb, but it is to verbalize a noun?

Tags: pragmatics, word-formation

As in "eat > eating", the meaning of the generated word would not make confusion, but if I make a word formation like "lamp(N) > *lamp(V)", it doesn't make sense, unless the generated word is lexicalized.

Comment: _"Verbing weirds language" -- Calvin_

Comment: Did you mean "not to verbalize a noun" as in your question's heading, or "it *is* to verbalize a noun" as your question's text suggests?

Comment: When you say "to nominalize a verb", do you specifically mean by adding -ing, or do you mean more generally to coin a noun which you derive from a verb? Since you don't give an example usage of your example noun "eating", it is not clear what you expect people to think you mean by it.

Comment: Your presupposition seems unclear, vague, and possibly incorrect. You can't *lamp* something but I can guess what it might mean, and you can, in fact, *torch* something. (And apparently, you *can* [lamp](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lamp).)

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you give, you're using a standard derivational suffix of English: *-ing* attached to a verb forms a *gerund noun*, that is, a noun referring to the action itself.

But in the second example, you don't use any standard verb-forming suffix. You just treat the noun as a verb. If you want to make an understandable verb, you can use a suffix like *-ify*: while it sounds ridiculous, "lampify" clearly means to turn something into a lamp.

For a less ridiculous-sounding example, shifting a problem to another subfield of linguistics might involve *semanticizing* or *morphologizing* it. Both of those verbs (and the gerund nouns derived from them) are clear in their meaning, even though I just invented them on the spot.